# How to send SMS Via bluetooth using PyOBEX?

Tags: python, bluetooth, sms, obex

Am trying to send SMS through Bluetooth to my phone using PyOBEX but it returning
`<PyOBEX.common.UnknownResponse object at 0x107f2bd50>`.

### **Here is my code**

```
port = 4
target_address = "C0:3D:03:43:E1:5A"
message = 'BEGIN:BMSG\r\nVERSION:1.0\r\nSTATUS:UNREAD\r\nTYPE:SMS_GSM\r\nFOLDER:telecom/msg/outbox\r\nBEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\nFN:Yona Mahundi\r\nN:Yona Mahundi\r\nTEL:+255762637233\r\nEMAIL:yona@gmail.com\r\nEND:VCARD\r\nBEGIN:BENV\r\nBEGIN:BBODY\r\nCHARSET:UTF-8\r\nLENGTH:34\r\nBEGIN:MSG\r\ni am a text.\r\nEND:MSG\r\nEND:BBODY\r\nEND:BENV\r\nEND:BMSG\r\n'

client = MessageAccessProfileClient(target_address, port)

result = client.connect()

if not isinstance(result, responses.ConnectSuccess):
        sys.stderr.write("Failed to connect to phone.\n")
        sys.exit(1)

resp = client.put('telecom/msg/outbox', message.encode(),header_list=[
                         headers.Type(b"x-bt/message"), headers.AppParameters(b'\x0b\x01\00\x0b\x00\x14\x01\x01')
                     ])
```

## **My ENV**

- OS: **MacOS Version 12.0.1**
- Memory : **16GB**
- Processor : **2.5 GHz**
- Python Version : **3.7.11**
- PyOBEX Version : **0.29**